# How to disable automatic cropping of WMS layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

When importing a WMS layer, QGIS automatically limits the extents of the image to the CRS area of use.

Is there any (GDAL) setting/variable to prevent this annoying behavior?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are looking for. Is the goal to download large extents from the WMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, wrong question for QGIS. The problem arises in MapProxy.

The extents limitation of my WMS layers takes place inside MapProxy, which serves the WMS images.

MapProxy limits the WMS service to the EPSG area of use.